# Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call when creating instance of Codable class

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a new instance of a codable class, but I am not sure how to:

```
var x = Articles();
```

gives me the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call

```
class Articles: Codable {
    let value: [Article]? 
}
```

I don't understand since this is a parameterless class.  I have no idea what the from parameter is all about.

Comment: See the `init(from:)` method in `Decodable`.

Comment: I added my own initializer without a param but it didn't resolve it.  I kind of thought that would: class Articles: Codable {
    init() {
        value = nil;
    }
    
    let value: [Article]?
}

Comment: Eventually got it to work.  What threw me off was the need for the parameter.  Other programming languages have a different behaviour in which constructors have to be explicitly defined even if the subclass has a constructor.  It works quite different in Swift.  I couldn't even create a constructor that set only some of the Codable properties (had to be all).  This is also significantly different to how other programming languages operate (like JAVA, or C#).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand since this is a parameterless class. I have no idea
>   what the from parameter is all about.

I get no error when I run the following:

```
class Articles: Codable {
    let value: [Articles]?

    init() {
        value = nil
        print("in init()")
    }
}

var x = Articles()
```

output:

```
in init()
```

And without `init()`:

```
class Articles: Codable {
    let value: [Articles]?

//    init() {
//        value = nil
//        print("in init()")
//    }
}

var x = Articles()  //Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call
```

First, read [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html):

> **Automatic Initializer Inheritance**
>
> As mentioned above, subclasses do not inherit their superclass
>   initializers by default. However, superclass initializers are
>   automatically inherited if certain conditions are met. In practice,
>   this means that you do not need to write initializer overrides in many
>   common scenarios, and can inherit your superclass initializers with
>   minimal effort whenever it is safe to do so.
>
> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you
>   introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> Rule 1 If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

If you look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable), `Codable` is a `typealias` for the `Decodable` protocol (a protocol is like an interface in java).  [Protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) specify functions that a class must implement if they adopt the protocol.  Your `Articles` class adopts the `Decodable` protocol.  However, the docs for [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) say,

> `init(from: Decoder)`
>
> Creates a new instance by decoding from the given decoder. Required.
>   **Default implementation provided**.

Protocols can actually ***implement*** functions by using [extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID521), which are then inherited by the class adopting the protocol.

As a result, the only *designated* initializer for your class is the one defined in the `Decodable` protocol, which takes one argument--which you inherit according to `Rule 1`.  On the other hand, when you explicitly define another designated initializer in your class that takes no arguments, then you will call that initializer when you provide no arguments.

Comment: I understand inheritance.  I'm thrown off by the difference with how constructors are used when a class inherits another class.  Other programming languages handle require those constructors to be explicitly defined in your class and constructors are not inherited.  It's the implementation details in how Swift handles inheritance that I need to understand better, I'll give you that..

Comment: @user1060500, Yeah.  It's actually protocols that we are talking about here.  See my comments at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: *constructors are not inherited* -- I posted a quote from the docs about that, too.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in putting this useful information together.